# Eclipse metrics plugin for C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, plugins, metrics, lines-of-code

Does anyone know a good metrics plugin for Eclipse that works with **C++** ?

I'm looking for lines of code mainly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the open source [Eclipse Metrics plugin](http://eclipse-metrics.sourceforge.net), but i personally prefer ProjectCodeMeter which integrates with eclipse as external [metrics tool](http://www.projectcodemeter.com).

Comment: I installed the plug-in in my Eclipse Juno (3.8.1) and the Metrics panel only showed up for a Java project, not with a CDT-based project. ProjectCodeMeter is Windows-only and its "integration" with Eclipse is limited to running itself as an external program, which is not really integrated.

Answer (score 6):

Eclipse Metrics is very powerful but only works for Java unfortunately.
Project Code Meter is a professional, comprehensive, but also expensive tool.
cccc is an awful, hacked command line tool for Windows only.
However [Code Analyzer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeanalyze-gpl/) is a simple, free graphics tool that works great with C and C++.

It took a look at the help to get started though, you need to:

- select an extension set from the Tools->Extension Set->Select menu (I chose the C set)
- right click on the "New" Code Set icon and do "Add Branch", then navigate to your source root folder
- click run, and here you go:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know there is no code metrics plugin for C++/CDT, but you can use [cccc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cccc/)

But i guess you already knew about it :)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

We have been working on an Eclipse plug-in called metriculator. Its still under development but some major metrics (e.g. LSLOC, McCabe, EfferentCoupling) are already implemented.

See http://sinv-56013.edu.hsr.ch/redmine/projects/metricular/wiki/Documentation for more details.

EDIT:
Above link is dead, you can use https://github.com/ideadapt/metriculator instead.

Comment: Nice integration with Eclipse, but ignores .c files.